# My auth.log file, size is quite huge. How can I reduce it? Will trucate command work?

Tags: log

This is my auth file size:

```
-rw-r-----   1 syslog    adm            
  26451675 Mar 27 15:23 auth.log
```

Will `sudo truncate -s 0 /var/log/auth.log`  is reducing the size. Will it impact my system?

Regards

Comment: 26Mb is not huge ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Investigate `logrotate` (`man logrotate;less /etc_logrotate.conf`. `logrotate` knows how to coordinate with the logging process to avoid the "unlinked but active" problem.

Comment: Thanks!  quite helpful

Answer (score 1):

Yes that will work.

Maybe compress it if you want to keep it? It will end up about 10% of the original file.

```
 sudo -i
 cd /var/log/
 gzip auth.log.gz auth.log
```

and then do

```
 > /var/log/auth.log
```

(or use your truncate; `>` will just blow the file empty).

---

Never use `rm` for this: it will remove permissions and if the file is written too by a server it can crash it.